# Add Windows Explorer context menu options to Visual Studio context menu

Tags: visual-studio, windows-explorer

Rather than using loads of half-supported add-ins on Visual Studio (2012), I would like to be able to right-click a file or folder in Solution Explorer or a document tab and have all the options I have on Windows explorer (e.g. Tortoise SVN, edit with Sublime Text, etc.). Is there an add-in, or something quick I can write myself that will allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this extension in gallery
[link](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5142e8de-6990-4189-afa3-85bdc5ffbb30)
.

Works ok for VS2010 Ultimate

Comment: Also works for VS2012 Ultimate. Very useful, thanks.

Comment: Does not work for VS 2015. The answer seems outdated.

Comment: Would love this or an equivalent extension for >=2015